# How to apply regexp to TextEdit like in Qt Widgets?

Tags: regex, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Is there a way to apply regexp (while input some text) to `TextEdit` QML element like in QtWidgets?

In QtWidgets you need to create `QRegExp` and `QValidator`, then set pattern for `QRegExp`, create a `QValidator` with the pattern and finally call `setValidator()` on `QLineEdit`.

Is there a way to implement something similar in QML? Or the only way is to workaround is by exploiting some JavaScript and/or C++ code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add text validation you should switch from `TextEdit` to `TextInput` type. The latter has a [`validator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#validator-prop) property. It reads from the documentation:

> Allows you to set a validator on the TextInput. When a validator is set the TextInput will only accept input which leaves the text property in an acceptable or intermediate state. The accepted signal will only be sent if the text is in an acceptable state when enter is pressed.
>
> Currently supported validators are IntValidator, DoubleValidator and **RegExpValidator**.

[`RegExpValidator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-regexpvalidator.html)
provides the `regExp` property which holds the actual regular expression to be applied to the input text.

Here is a minimum example which accepts only digits and `a` (one or more digit/`a` - both uppercase and lowercase):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true
    
    TextInput {
        focus: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /[0-9aA]+/ }
    }
}
```